# jquery.validate.js corrupting twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, modal-dialog

When using jquery.validate (For email purposes.) in conjunction with twitter bootstrap, modal windows aren't able to close unless you click outside of box (It renders buttons useless.). There is a `.cancel` class for suppressing validation in the jquery code but that doesn't seem to help.

I created a stripped down [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eldereko/N9jR5/), as well as the actual [page](http://cincitucky.com/booty-q.php) I'm working on (Specifically the info buttons for shirts and skateboards.).

I've spent the last five hours trying to find a solution, any insight regarding this problem you might have would absolutely rock!

Comment: put the code used for validate and modal in the fiddle, not in external file on your site. Can't easily review code in external file, or modify it

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Between your critique and @Sparky's instruction I have a much better understanding on how to properly utilize jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine when I replace your 4 or 5-year old version (1.5.5) of jQuery Validate with the latest, version 1.10.0

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Working:  http://jsfiddle.net/QAkpk/

Also see documentation:  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

---

And here is how to properly use jsFiddle, for your edification:

http://jsfiddle.net/rMt8g/

Note that only the *content* of `<body></body>` is placed within the `HTML` pane.  The external files are included using the `Add Resources` panel and the jQuery version is selected from the `Choose Framework` panel.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually downloaded the latest version of jQuery Validate and due to incompetence on my part didn't apply it properly. Very frustrating and very embarrassing. If it is of any consolation, I will be much more studious before I ask another question on stack overflow. Also, thank you for informing me on the proper way to utilize jsFiddle. And lastly, I concur with @Steve on your use of edification. Many lessons learned.